# Pulsar issue with connecting to the bookie when running as standalone in docker

Tags: apache-pulsar

After starting cluster producer, consumer, and pulsar itself, it seems there are cases where pulsar is not accepting the messages.
Following is the error:

```
pulsar           | 2023-08-12T09:09:48,860+0000 [pulsar-io-19-11] ERROR org.apache.bookkeeper.proto.PerChannelBookieClient - Could not connect to bookie: [id: 0x441633f6, L:/172.22.0.2:42746]/172.18.0.2:38615, current state CONNECTING :
pulsar           | io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /172.18.0.2:38615
```

This issue does not happen for the first time the pulsar is started in standalone mode , but is seen when we start from the second time onwards.
Please help me out to understand what could have gone wrong. Does standalone cluster started with following command has bookie enabled?

```
docker run -it -p 6650:6650  -p 8080:8080 --mount source=pulsardata,target=/pulsar/data --mount source=pulsarconf,target=/pulsar/conf apachepulsar/pulsar:3.0.1 bin/pulsar standalone
```

If not, does this error cause any issues with message communication between producer and consumer?